# Is there any execute("java statement") method in java like python(exec()) do?

Tags: java, runtime, exec

I want to get a `String` from the user like `"System.out.println(\"Hello World!\");"` or `"int x = 2;"` and then execute that input at runtime in java, I know that in python there is a built in function called `exec()` that do what exactly what I want here.

Comment: Although Python's `eval()` and `exec()` are not identical, they are close enough for this purpose that the answer is the same.  Especially since it's "no".

Comment: Java is a compiled language, Python is an interpreted one. For Java is not a simple task to do compilation on the fly.